# How to push an array in a class data in a vue js component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an empty `object` in my datas like :

```
data: () => {
  return {
    lines: []
  }
}
```

and I want to push some arrays in from a function I defined in "mounted" with a constructor like that:

```
function setLine() {
  class Line {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.stroke = stroke;
    }
  }
  let x1 = localStorage.getItem("x1")
  let y1 = localStorage.getItem("y1")
  let x2 = localStorage.getItem("x2")
  let y2 = localStorage.getItem("y2")
  let stroke = localStorage.getItem("stroke")
  console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
  let lines = [
    new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
  ]
  localStorage.setItem("lines", JSON.stringify(lines))
}
```

it works quite well for adding one line in my storage, but even if I tried to write :

`this.objects = lines`, it doesn't update my objects in datas...

Can anybody tell me how I can do that please?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand & replicate your problem:

```js
const localStorageMock = {
  x1: 1,
  y1: 2,
  x2: 3,
  y2: 4,
  stroke: 5,
}

function setLine() {
  class Line {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.stroke = stroke;
    }
  }

  let x1 = localStorageMock["x1"]
  let y1 = localStorageMock["y1"]
  let x2 = localStorageMock["x2"]
  let y2 = localStorageMock["y2"]
  let stroke = localStorageMock["stroke"]

  const newLine = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)

  let lines = [
    new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
  ]
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      lines: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lines = setLine()
    console.log(this.lines)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The snippet above doesn't change anything, because `setLine()` doesn't return anything. (OK, it changes `this.lines` empty array to **undefined**.)

#### SUGGESTION 1

```js
const localStorageMock = {
  x1: 1,
  y1: 2,
  x2: 3,
  y2: 4,
  stroke: 5,
}

function setLine() {
  class Line {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.stroke = stroke;
    }
  }

  let x1 = localStorageMock["x1"]
  let y1 = localStorageMock["y1"]
  let x2 = localStorageMock["x2"]
  let y2 = localStorageMock["y2"]
  let stroke = localStorageMock["stroke"]

  const newLine = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)

  let lines = [
    new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
  ]
  return lines
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      lines: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lines = setLine()
    console.log(this.lines)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### IF YOU WANT TO ADD MORE LINES

```js
const localStorageMock = {
  x1: 1,
  y1: 2,
  x2: 3,
  y2: 4,
  stroke: 5,
}

function setLine(lineArr = []) {
  class Line {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.stroke = stroke;
    }
  }

  let x1 = localStorageMock["x1"]
  let y1 = localStorageMock["y1"]
  let x2 = localStorageMock["x2"]
  let y2 = localStorageMock["y2"]
  let stroke = localStorageMock["stroke"]

  const newLine = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)

  let lines = [
    ...lineArr,
    new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
  ]
  return lines
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      lines: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lines = setLine() // adding the first line
    this.lines = setLine(this.lines) // adding the second line
    this.lines = setLine(this.lines) // adding the third line
    console.log(this.lines)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

#### SUGGESTION 2

```js
const localStorageMock = {
  x1: 1,
  y1: 2,
  x2: 3,
  y2: 4,
  stroke: 5,
}

function setLine({
  x1,
  y1,
  x2,
  y2,
  stroke
}) {
  class Line {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke) {
      this.x1 = x1;
      this.y1 = y1;
      this.x2 = x2;
      this.y2 = y2;
      this.stroke = stroke;
    }
  }
  return new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, stroke)
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      lines: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.lines = [
      setLine(localStorageMock),
      setLine(localStorageMock),
      setLine(localStorageMock),
      setLine(localStorageMock),
      setLine(localStorageMock),
    ]
    console.log(this.lines)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```